# Handle SQLiteOpenHelper when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The apps I try to create is a `ViewPager` then consist of `Fragments`.

Each `Fragment` has different data, because the got it from `Database`.

I send the Database class from `Fragment Activity` to `Fragment` inside the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Here is the code :

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.create(position, student, getApplicationContext(), mDbStudent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

**mDbStudent** is the Database class.

I open my **mDbStudent** at `onCreate`

And I close my **mDbStudent** when `onDestroy`

The problem I have is when The orientation changes, the `mDbStudent` was destroyed
but the `fragment` still loading the data from database, therefore the error occurs.

I try to get the mDbStudent in the `Fragment` when `onAttach`, but when I move the pages very fast, it log stated I didn't close the **mDbStudent**

**My question is** Is there a way to handle the **mDbStudent** when orientation change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to instantiate your database outside of the Activity. Most likely, you'll be using the database in many Activies and Fragments, right? You can create a static singleton, like this:

```
public class Global {
    private static Global instance = null;
    private Context context;

    public Global( Context context ) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static getInstance( Context context ) {
        if( instance == null )
            instance = new Global( context );
        return instance;
    }

    public SQLiteOpenHelper getDatabase() {
        return ... ;
    }
}
```

Then, in your Activity, you can call:

```
Global.getInstance( this ).getDatabase()...
```

This stores the application's Context, so you can access that in Global instance whereever needed... even if the Activity has since been destroyed.

This will also allow you to open the database once and keep it open, even through orientation changes. In my apps, I generally leave the DB open until the app is closed explicitly. If you have a single-Activity app, I would open the database, if closed, in `onStart` and close it in `onUserLeaveHint()`. This will only close the database if the use leaves the app, but not on orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I have no problem with the `Context`. My problem is when to close and open the `mDbStudent`. Do you know how to handle it?

Comment: Thanks, but I open my database the onCreate, when the orientation change it will open again. how to fix it? because if it open twice the logcat will appear I never close the DB

Comment: See above -- open the database in onStart, but only do that if it's not open.

Comment: I don't understand why your getInstance() does not stated anything to return, but you return instance at the bottom of the function